# Coloring of standard deviation shading using geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, geom-ribbon

I am working with a data frame, where I have columns:

```
     species  replicate  position DOY   RED.PEAK RED.PEAK.SD FAR.RED.PEAK FAR.RED.PEAK.SD
1 LINGONBERRY         1      LOW   1 0.10218177 0.050779465   0.14498610      0.04848566
2 LINGONBERRY         1      LOW  10 0.12089622 0.039990500   0.18177440      0.03263417
3 LINGONBERRY         1      LOW   2 0.10861619 0.039823347   0.20582430      0.05709061
4 LINGONBERRY         1      LOW   3 0.05398631 0.006064099   0.10750730      0.01954550
5 LINGONBERRY         1      LOW   4 0.08722205 0.017874483   0.14446139      0.03133565
6 LINGONBERRY         1      LOW   5 0.04872162 0.028601630   0.09535204      0.02216967
```

Where species, replicate, position and time are my cases, RED.PEAK and FAR.RED.PEAK are my values and RED.PEAK.**SD** and FAR.RED.PEAK.**SD** are **standard deviations** of RED.PEAK and FAR.RED.PEAK.

I am using ggplot to plot different species (3) with facet_grid,
different positions (2) with linetype,
and different replicates (3) with colors.

```
NEW.gridplot <- ggplot(new.plot.table,aes(DOY, RED.PEAK, group=interaction(position, replicate)))+
  scale_x_discrete(limit = c("II Feb", "I Mar", "II Mar", "I Apr", "II Apr", "I May", "II May", "I Jun", "II Jun", "I Jul"))+ 
  facet_grid(.~species)+
  geom_line(aes(color=replicate, linetype=position), size=2)+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("dashed", "solid")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('black', 'red', 'blue')) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = RED.PEAK - RED.PEAK.SD,
                  ymax = RED.PEAK + RED.PEAK.SD), alpha = 0.1) +
  myplotting

print(NEW.gridplot)
```

[see an example of ggplot I am having now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU4Zq.png)

and it works well. I would like to, however, colour the shading to black, blue and red in geom_ribbon as well.

```
 geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = RED.PEAK - RED.PEAK.SD,
                  ymax = RED.PEAK + RED.PEAK.SD), alpha = 0.1, fill=(values = c('black', 'red', 'blue')))
```

did not work, delivering error
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (150): fill
Then:

```
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ORANGE.PEAK - ORANGE.PEAK.SD,
                  ymax = ORANGE.PEAK + ORANGE.PEAK.SD), alpha = 0.1, fill=replicate)+
                  scale_fill_manual(values = c('black', 'red', 'blue'))
```

did not work either, delivering error
Error in rep(value[[k]], length.out = n) :
attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'

Looking for a solution to have my shadings from geom_ribbon the same colors as their corresponding lines from geom_line.

Comment: Have yu tried `color` instead of `fill`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your second try is almost correct. However the `fill=...` should be inside the `aes` function and then you need another ```scale_fill_manual````:

```
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = RED.PEAK - RED.PEAK.SD,
                  ymax = RED.PEAK + RED.PEAK.SD, fill = c("black","red","blue")), alpha = 0.1, show.legend = F) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black","red","blue"))
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! Putting the `fill=` inside `aes` was the trick. Very appreciated.